# Java Threads

Tags: java, multithreading

How do I implement a ThreadPoolExecutor? What needs to be done to use it?

Comment: Do you need to implement a new one, or just use a thread pool? If the latter there are several implementations in the API

Answer (score 8):

The API Specification for the [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) class has four constructors which can be used to create an instance of the `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

The `Executors` class also has methods such as [`newCachedThreadPool`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool()) and [`newFixedThreadPool`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)) methods, but those are only listed as returning an `ExecutorService`, so it doesn't necessarily have to be a `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

For more general information on `Executors` and the Java concurrency package, the [Lesson: Concurrency](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) from [The Java Tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/index.html) has more information. In particular, the [Executors](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) and [Thread Pools](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) section may be of interest.

Answer (score 3):

[Executor](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) is a interface.  Implementing it allows clients to pass you runnable tasks, which are then executed in a particular manner.  [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) is one class implementing that interface (and ExecutorService).  It uses a thread pool so you can have multiple threads executing jobs without needing a new thread for every job.  ThreadPoolExecutor can be subclassed, or you can just instantiate it with one of the public constructors.

Other methods, such as [Executors.newFixedThreadPool](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)), return a thread pool of some kind though not (necessarily) a ThreadPoolExecutor.

Answer (score 2):

Java Concurrency in Practice - Addison Wesley ISBN:0321349601
I used this book to learn about Executors. I has a bunch of good examples you can steal.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start with the tutorial for this class http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html